# Changing the UITableView height based on scroll in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to change the height of my `UITableView` based on the scrolled content. Right now I do it by getting the `scrollViewDidScroll` event and then getting scrolled value and then change the height. Here is my code (for simplification I omitted the irrelevant code):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
float currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
double delta = currentOffset - storedOffset;

if(delta != 0)
{
    delta = abs(delta);

    CGRect newListFrame = myTableView.frame;
    float newListHeight = newListFrame.size.height + delta;
    newListFrame.size.height = newListHeight;

    myTableView.frame = newListFrame;
}

storedOffset = currentOffset;
```

}

But this approach is wrong because with this approach my `UITableView`'s content is scrolled only a little bit and that's not what I want. I just want to get the value of that list that would be scrolled without actually scrolling it. Is there any way to do that? I thing I could get raw finger moved event but can I get it on `UITableVIew`? Can I do something like this using a `UITableView` method?

Comment: Why do you want to make your tableview bigger? Won't it grow beyond screen boundaries at some point, making parts of your tableview unreachable?

Comment: You mean like what Facebook does when you are looking through your timeline it makes the bar at the top smaller and makes tableview bigger?

Comment: Hmm... I mean line in safari. When I scroll down then top bar is shrink and in that place content is grown. @ophychius Yeah, I know, but I in my code I secure for it. I just not mention that in my code.